# How to export multiple layers as separate JPGs from multiple PSD files in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing

**My setup:**

- I have about 200 PSD files.
- Each of those PSD files contain different number of layers (from 2 to 9).
- All of layers in those PSD files have default names (Layer 1, Layer 2, Layer 3, etc.).

**My goal:**

I would like to batch export **all** of those layers from **all** of those PSD files as **separate** JPG files.

**What I've already tried:**

1. Open one of those PSD files.
2. Start recording Action (named **"Ex"**), and click `File > Export > Layers to Files`. Settings window pops up:

   - 2.1. Leave *Destination* the same as source folder.
   - 2.2. Leave default *File Name Prefix* (it is the name of the current PSD file).
   - 2.3. Chose JPG as the *File Type*.
   - 2.4. Click *Run*.
   - 2.5. PS exports those few layers and then I delete them (just for keeping things tidy before running batch stuff).
3. Close the PSD file.
4. Click `File > Automate > Batch`
5. Chose Action **"Ex"** to Play.
6. Chose *Source Folder* containing my 200 PSD files
7. Chose *Destination Folde* - other than the source folder.
8. Hit *OK*.

But the result is bad - the exported files all have **the same prefix** (taken from this firstly opened PSD's filename) which was stored in the "Ex" Action recording, so Photoshop overwrites those exported JPGs again, and again, and again, while performing this "Ex" Action on next PSD files in queue.

**In short words:**

I just can't make PS to export those layers from those PSD files, with unique names. I just don't believe it's even possible without some custom script.

Can You help me somehow? I would appreciate any help in the fear of doing all this stuff by hand, file by file. :/

PS: Photoshop version 2020 (21.0.3. Release)

Comment: Have you tried ticking the `Override Action "Save As" Commands` option for the batch?

Comment: There are a lot of answers with different export scenarios scripts, have you tried to go through them? I believe you can salvage parts to build what you want, it shouldn't be a difficult script.